# How to avoid NULL value in IF EXISTS statement within transaction?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, t-sql, concurrency, transactions

I have thousands of threads executing concurrently. **The first type** of thread is T-SQL query like this one:

```
DECLARE @import_id int

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT [id]
        FROM [dbo].[Import]
        WHERE created IS NULL
        )
    SELECT @import_id = [id]
    FROM [dbo].[Import]
    WHERE created IS NULL
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Import] ([startdate])
    SELECT GETDATE()

    SELECT @import_id = @@IDENTITY
END
```

**The second type** of thread is T-SQL query like this one:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Import] SET created = GETDATE() WHERE created IS NULL
```

All of these types of T-SQL queries executing in **transactions** with type **Read Commited**.

**The problem:** Sometimes, **the first query**, returns `@import_id = NULL`, but I am expecting some value there in `@import_id`.

The question is how to avoid this case with **Read Commited** transaction type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems a strange design, but I imagine you've left out a lot.

One way you can fix this is remove the `IF` test, because the data would appear to be changing between the `IF` test and the `SELECT`. So instead:

```
SELECT @import_id = [id]
FROM [dbo].[Import]
WHERE created IS NULL;

IF @import_id IS NULL BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Import] ([startdate])
    SELECT GETDATE();

    SELECT @import_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); -- SCOPE_IDENTITY() is recommended over @@IDENTITY
END;
```

Note you probably want a `TOP 1` and an `ORDER BY` for your `SELECT`.

Of course as shown you might obtain a `@import_id` where `created is null` but your other thread could set it to `GETDATE()` even before `@import_id` is returned to the client. But I assume you've thought of that.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your solution solved my problem. I have a couple of related questions: 1. Will it be ok if I add `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` hint in select statement (for more reliability)? 2. When I add `ORDER BY` I am catching deadlocks (with `TOP 1` and without `ORDER BY` everything is ok).

Comment: and thank you for the suggestion about `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. This is important.

Comment: @Phil `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` might help prevent the other thread from changing it before you return - but it might change it a fraction of a second after, so it really depends on how those records are used in the wider context. With regard to `TOP 1 ORDER BY` all I can say is, without it do you select from the correct row? You need to first ensure the behaviour is correct, then solve any issues that arise. So if the behaviour is correct without the order by, don't change it.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help and detailed answer.